# What is the proper way to toggle button caption in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a child component named `Earth` having a single button. We are allowed to press the button multiple times to start and stop spinning the earth.

```
<button @onclick="Toggle">
    @if (isMoving)
    {
        <text>Stop Spinning</text>
    }
    else
    {
        <text>Start Spinning</text>
    }
</button>

@code {
    private bool isMoving = true;

    private void Toggle()
    {
        isMoving = !isMoving;
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

The caption of the button must be toggled with 2 mutually exclusive options `Stop Spinning` and `Start Spinning`.

I consume the `Earth` component in a routable component named `God` as follows.

```
@page "/God"

<Earth />
```

I launch the application and navigate to `God`. So far so good. But if I press the button, I got an error:

> An unhandled error has occurred. Reload

When debugging it, I am pointed to  an extremely long code. Here is the trimmed version.

```
var Module=typeof Module!=="undefined"?Module:{};var moduleOverrides={};var key;for(key in Module){if(Module.hasOwnProperty(key)){moduleOverrides[key]=Module[key]}}var arguments_=[];var thisProgram="./this.program";var quit_=function(status,toThrow){throw toThrow};var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=false;var ENVIRONMENT_IS_SHELL=false;ENVIRONMENT_IS_WEB=typeof window==="object";ENVIRONMENT_IS_WORKER=typeof importScripts==="function";ENVIRONMENT_IS_NODE=typeof process==="object"&&typeof process.versions==="object"&&typeof treaming compile failed: "+reason);err("falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation");instantiateArrayBuffer(receiveInstantiatedSource)})})}else{return instantiateArrayBuffer(receiveInstantiatedSource)}}if(Module["instantiateWasm"]){try{var
```

## Question

What is the proper way to toggle button caption in Blazor?

## Edit

I tested with two browsers: Chrome (does not work) and Edge (works).

[image]

Comment: I submitted this issue to github: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24184

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<button @onclick="Toggle">@Caption</button>

@code {
    private string Caption => isMoving ? "Start Spinning" : "Stop Spinning";


    private bool isMoving = true;

 
    private void Toggle()
    {
        isMoving = !isMoving;
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```